# K8s Cronjob Rolling Restart Every Day

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have one pod that I want to automatically restart once a day. I've looked at the Cronjob documentation and I think I'm close, but I keep getting an Exit Code 1 error. I'm not sure if there's an obvious error in my .yaml. If not, I can post the error log as well. Here's my code:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-restart
spec:
  schedule: "0 20 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: kubectl
              image: bitnami/kubectl 
              command:
                - 'kubectl'
                - 'rollout'
                - 'restart'
                - 'deployment my-deployment'
```

Comment: Is the job pod being created? If so, what do the logs for the pod say?

Comment: The job pod does create. Here's the error message:

```
Containers:
  kubectl:
    Container ID:  docker://f0
    Image:         bitnami/kubectl
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://bitnami/kubectl
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      kubectl
      rollout
      restart
      deployment lesson-service-deployment
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 05 May 2021 13:00:46 -0700
      Finished:     Wed, 05 May 2021 13:00:47 -0700
    Ready:          False

```

Comment: That's from `kubectl logs <your_pod>`? It looks more like the `describe` output of the pod.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, the only message I'm getting back from the logs is this

error: the server doesn't have a resource type "deployment my-deployment" so do 'depoloyment' and 'my-deployment need to be on separate lines?

Comment: That means either you are not specifying the correct namespace or the pod doesn't have the correct permissions to interact with the k8s API. k8s API authorization to pods is typically done via service accounts.

Comment: Sure enough, once I moved the deployment name to the next line, the next error was this: Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.apps "my-deployment" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"

Answer (score 2):

You would need to give it permissions to access the API, that means making a ServiceAccount and some RBAC policy objects (Role, RoleBinding) and then set `serviceAccountName` in your pod spec there.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a good place to start. Seems like doing a rolling update to pods at a set interval would be something you could specify on the deployment of the pod itself vs. a separate Cronjob, but that's a whole different issue. ;)

Comment: You might want to look at ecosystem tools that implement this more safely and efficiently. For just one case, this is fine but if you end up doing it a bunch there's many "reaper" style tools that can delete a pod after N seconds (86400 in this case).